# PostGIS query with external bounding box

Tags: postgis, query

I am editing a shapefile as wide as an island. The data are stored in a Postgres/PostGIS database. I want to display only features from my defined bounding box. The bounding box itself is a custom layer that i made myself and it is not stored in the database.

How can this be achieved?

Update: the PostGIS manual has this particular example

```sql
SELECT
  m.name,
  sum(ST_Length(r.the_geom))/1000 as roads_km
FROM
  bc_roads AS r,
  bc_municipality AS m
WHERE
  ST_Contains(m.the_geom,r.the_geom)
GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY roads_km;
```

Since I dont have the bounding box geometry in the database, is there another way to mimic the bounding box geometry?
It would be something like this

```sql
SELECT
 layer,
 (x1,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y2), (x2, y1) AS bbox
FROM
 layer
WHERE
 ST_Contains(layer.the_geom, bbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store your query extent in the database, but the best option is still to make a `geometry` type from it. I would recommend making a WKT represenation of your geometry by whatever means you deem appropriate, then just use [`ST_GeomFromText`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html) in a query, e.g.:

```sql
-- wkt is a WKT representation of your box
SELECT *
FROM bc_roads
WHERE bc_roads.geom && ST_GeomFromText(wkt);
```